# Error on the creation of ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application ") in web worker

Tags: javascript, web, activex, worker, activexobject

I have a simple HTML file and a couple of `JS` files which perform async operation using web worker. I need to create `ActiveX` object for Outlook in order to get the Outlook Object Model functionality to retrieve a large set of Outlook tasks. I create `ActiveXObject` ("Outlook.Application") in web worker `JS` file. But when I browse my HTML file through `IE10` I'm getting `Automation server can't create object` on the `ActiveXObject` creation step.

As far as I know this error is about Internet Security settings. So I enabled `ActiveX` and set `Enable for Initializing and Script ActiveX controls not marked as safe` under the `ActiveX` controls and plug-ins in `IE`. But it doesn't help. The interactions in `JS` files are OK as I checked the work without using `ActiveX`.

Could you please advise how to resolve it and if it's possible to use `ActiveX` with web worker?

Thank you in advance.

Here is the HTML and scripts

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="my_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="javascript:showTasksCount();" value="Show Tasks count" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**my_script.js**

```
function display(count) {
        alert("Number of tasks: " + count);
}

function showTasksCount() {
    var myWorker = new Worker("web_worker.js");

    myWorker.onmessage = function (oEvent) {
        display(oEvent.data);
    };

    myWorker.postMessage("");
}
```

and

**web_worker.js**

```
onmessage = function (oEvent) {  
    var outlook = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");

    var count = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(1).Folders("Tasks").Items.Count;
    postMessage(count);
};
```

Comment: Posting your html and JavaScript files here will increase the likelihood of you receiving a helpful response.

Comment: the code is in the initial post updated